# Output to stderr in SpiderMonkey

Tags: javascript, stderr, spidermonkey

Is it possible from within the script executed by SpiderMonkey (passed with -f or -e option) to output a string value to `stderr`?

I do not want to lose the possibility of writing to `stdout` (as `print()` does by default), so changing the standard output file (`JS_STDOUT`) is not an option.

Throwing an exception (and not catching it) would be one way to get something to `stderr`, however the JavaScript execution stops at that point.

Another way I thought of is to call a string value as a function, which results in a `TypeError` (output to `stderr`), only I would have to make sure the quotes get escaped within the message:

```
$ js -e 'var m="cannot create runtime"; eval("'"'"'" + m + "'"'"'()");'
-e:1: TypeError: "cannot create runtime" is not a function
```

Is there a better way to do this?